# Why does Date.strptime omit the time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I ran the following command:

```
Date.strptime('04/16/2013 06:00 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
```

I am trying to get the DateTime object for the string provided.

Instead I am getting:

```
 => #<Date: 2013-04-16 ((2456399j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

It seems that Ruby is omitting the time, and this is how it gets saved to the database in my Rails application, except it adds 5AM as the default time.

How do I get it to parse the time as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime.strptime('04/16/2013 06:00 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
```

Comment: Don't just throw a fish, show how to catch them. In other words, explain why this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the actual time, try Time instead of Date.

Therefore:

```
Time.strptime('04/16/2013 06:00 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
```

instead.

Comment: Really, you should show how to use DateTime as it's more closely related to Date. And, you might want to explain the differences between Time and DateTime and why one might be used over the other depending on the situation.